# ThreeJS LineBasicMaterial не работает, как нарисовать простую толстую линию в 3D?

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js

`lineMat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color, linewidth: 5});` не работает в Windows

Нужен простой метод для рисования линий в 3D (сцена вращается):

`drawLine(measurement1, measurement2, color)` с толщиной линии более 1px

Я знаю о Windows & Angle. Большинство из найденных методов не работали или работают только в 2D или имеют проблемы внутри при реализации

П.С. Метод теперь (после ответа [@Stranger in the Q](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/188366/stranger-in-the-q)) выглядит так:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { MeshLine, MeshLineMaterial} from 'three.meshline';
```

```
  drawLine(measurement1, measurement2, color) {
    const geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    geometry.vertices.push(
      new THREE.Vector3( measurement1.X,  measurement1.Y,  measurement1.Z ),
      new THREE.Vector3( measurement2.X,  measurement2.Y,  measurement2.Z )
    );
    const line = new MeshLine();
    line.setGeometry( geometry );
    const material = new MeshLineMaterial({color});
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( line.geometry, material );
    this.scene.add( mesh );
}
```

Comment: я собирался вечерком добавить example в ответ =)

Comment: Спасибо большое! ) (могу удалить свой если хотите :))

Comment: зачем же, наоборот, только разместите ответом, и чтобы запустить можно было =), а то возможные будущие читающие, пришедшие из гугла могут расценить код в вопросе как пример не рабочего кода...

Comment: Есть еще один достаточно интересный способ, описанный тут: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2005/01/p1000-loop.pdf , и частично тут https://medium.com/@evanwallace/easy-scalable-text-rendering-on-the-gpu-c3f4d782c5ac , он технически сложен но очень хорош по производительности

Comment: Лучше поздно, чем никогда :) Есть еще вот такое в официальных примерах: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=fat#webgl_lines_fat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как Вы верно заметили это не реализовано в ANGLE, по этому в Windows приходится довольствоваться толщиной линии в 1 пиксель или использовать **триангуляцию полилинии**.

Вы можете сделать это сами, но конечно же для этого есть уже готовый код под Three.js, посмотрите на [`THREE.MeshLine`](https://github.com/spite/THREE.MeshLine)

https://www.clicktorelease.com/code/THREE.MeshLine/demo/index.html

Еще одна ссылка по теме https://mattdesl.svbtle.com/drawing-lines-is-hard